# How to open pdf file without save,save as,print using java?

Tags: java, pdf

I have used opening pdf using following code.

```
try
{
  File file = new File("Sample.pdf");
  java.awt.Desktop.getDeskTop().open(file);
  System.out.println("File opened successfully");
}catch(Exception ex)
{
  System.out.println("Error occurred: "+ex);
}
```

Now i want disable save,save as,print option in the pdf file before opening.I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936189/itext-disable-printing-copying-saving).but it wont work.

It throws following error occur.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/Recipient

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.cms.Recipient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

How to disable save,save as,print option for given pdf file?

Comment: You would have to edit the `pdf` file before opening, you can use ***[`itext`](http://itextpdf.com/)*** for that

Answer (score 0):

You missd the most importnat part of the link you attached, you need to use the [PdfWriter](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html) static fileds, i am not sure it support all your needs but at least some of them like [ALLOW_PRINTING](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#ALLOW_PRINTING).